# pub install dart-web-components failed

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-pub

Running pub install on dart-web-components gives an error:

```dart
Pub install fail, HttpParserException: Connection closed before full header was received

/dart-web-components/build.dart --changed=packages\args\args.dart --changed=packages\args\src\utils.dart --changed=packages\logging\...
Failed with error code 255
Unable to open file: C:/dartapps/dart-web-components/packages/web_components/component_build.dart'file:///C:/dartapps/dart-web-components/build.dart': Error: line 8 pos 1: library handler failed
```

import 'package:web_components/component_build.dart';
  ^

In build.dart file there's a string

```dart
import 'package:web_components/component_build.dart';
```

Editor shows an error

```dart
Cannot find referenced source: package:web_components/component_build.dart
```

component_build.dart contains errors

```dart
Cannot find referenced source: package:args/args.dart
Cannot find referenced source: package:web_components/dwc.dart
```

Comment: I'll ask the guy who works on this stuff to take a look.

Comment: There was a bug in pub with Windows, they fixed yesterday: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6513 , but still, I think wait the next Dart Editor release (hopefully, soon, as it often is)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. It seems that the Cache folder (Pub) has been corrupted.

I have deleted the folder Cache:

> C:\Users\<*UserName*>\AppData\Roaming\Pub

Then i run `pub install` from command line and it works.

My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so looking at your output:

```
Pub install fail, HttpParserException: Connection closed before full header was received
```

This is the real problem.

```
/dart-web-components/build.dart --changed=packages\args\args.dart --changed=packages\args\src\utils.dart --changed=packages\logging\...
Failed with error code 255
Unable to open file: C:/dartapps/dart-web-components/packages/web_components/component_build.dart'file:///C:/dartapps/dart-web-components/build.dart': Error: line 8 pos 1: library handler failed
```

These are just red herrings caused by the first problem.

I see you are on Windows. There is a known issue where the HTTP stuff has some intermittent non-deterministic failures. I'm still investigating, but it's hard to track down.

Do you get this error every time you try? How many attempts have you made?

Sorry for the trouble here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times. 
I now put dart-web-components to the default package-root directory.
Pub install now yields

```
Pub install fail, Package "html5lib" doesn't have a pubspec.yaml file.
```

However, the editor shows the same errors

```
Cannot find referenced source: package:web_components/component_build.dart
Cannot find referenced source: package:args/args.dart
```

etc. In almost every *.dart file

Answer (score 0):

Added this in pubscpec.yams

html5lib: 
    git: git://github.com/dart-lang/html5lib.git

Now I get again

```
Pub install fail, HttpParserException: Connection closed before full header was received
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you using an proxy to access the internet? DartEditor cann't set the proxy,so it cann't access the pub packages.